# <ul> list bullets are displaying in one place , but not in another

Tags: html, css, magento

please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/a-mark-of-the-danger-warning-htc-m8-phone-case.html) , if you search for text "**Device**", you can see it is displaying  2 times.

before text "Device" , 1st time, it showing **bullets**.in second time, it not showing bullets, but we used same code for both.

```
<ul>
<li>Device: HTC M8</li>
<li>Design: Art & Graphics</li>
<li>Material: Polycarbonate Hard Case</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and fix your question

Comment: Could be due to `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`. Check the stylesheet!

Comment: @Pugazh please check this link : http://prnt.sc/c76tcp , i removed `margin: 0 and padding: 0` but still not working for me

Comment: Add `list-style-type: disc;` for the `li`'s.

Comment: @Pugazh Thanks a lot for support....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add styling to it `list-style: initial;`, because everywhere you are using `list-style: none;` as default and this applies to the second one. If you have this styling already in place, then check that it would be by hierarchy higher than initial one.

Comment: when i add like this : `<ul style="list-style: initial;">` it worked fine, did you told to add like this or add code in stylesheet ?

Comment: You can add class to your ul tag, like this <ul class="my-class"> and then add ul.my-class{ list-style: initial; }      

That would be more clean way. The way you have, works as well, but inline styles should be avoided in general, so stylesheet is better option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.next-content-product ul li {list-style: inside disc;} /** add this in your style sheet **/
```

At first it working because you have define

```
.add-to-cart-wrapper li{list-style: inside disc;}
```

But in other it is not define